# How to solve this error "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0" in android

Tags: android, json, arraylist, google-sheets

I have implement an android app. I want to fetched data from google spreadsheet with the help of `getSpreadSheetData()` and `getSpreadSheetResponce()` method but I got error `StringIndexOutofBoundException`.

`MainActivity`

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    // action bar
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private ListView listView;

    ListAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    Utility utility;

    ArrayList<Personinfo> list;

    ArrayAdapter<Personinfo> arrayAdapter;

    AdapterFilter adapterfilter;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    Personinfo personinfo;

    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    Intent intent;

    private static final String FETCH_DATA_FROM_SPREADSHEET = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJBt8ZHAcnfwLhx0rYjC4ELImLInYxkOTTauw8PL6W4/gviz/tq";

    /** The pref name. */
    final String PREF_NAME = "pref";

    /** The hash map. */
    public static HashMap<Integer, List<String>> hashMap = null;

    /** The info array list. */
    public static ArrayList<String> infoArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#03A9F4")));
        actionBar.setTitle("Agarwal Association");

        list = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.Get_ContactDetails();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(0);
            String phoneno = cursor.getString(1);
            Personinfo personinfo = new Personinfo(name, phoneno);
            list.add(personinfo);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapterfilter = new AdapterFilter(this, R.layout.child_listview, list);
        Log.i("List", "" + list.get(0).getPhoneno());

        listView.setAdapter(adapterfilter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        getSpreadSheetData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                adapterfilter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(query);
                adapterfilter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // search action
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void getSpreadSheetData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        // hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        String result = getSpreadSheetResponce();

        Log.i("jsonResponse:", result);

        // remove the unnecessary parts from the response and construct a
        // JSON
        int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
        int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
        String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);

        try {
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            // String value = null;
            List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (mainObj != null) {
                JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("rows");
                if (list != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject innerJsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (innerJsonObject != null) {
                            JSONArray valuesJsonArray = innerJsonObject
                                    .getJSONArray("c");
                            if (valuesJsonArray != null) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < valuesJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject innerElem = valuesJsonArray
                                            .getJSONObject(j);
                                    if (innerElem != null) {
                                        String name = innerElem.getString("v");
                                        String phoneno = innerElem
                                                .getString("f");
                                        arraylist.add(name);
                                        arraylist.add(phoneno);
                                        hashMap.put(j, arraylist);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i("hashMap.get(0)", "" + hashMap.get(0));

            infoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            infoArrayList.addAll(hashMap.get(0));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getSpreadSheetResponce() {
        URL url;
        String responce = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(FETCH_DATA_FROM_SPREADSHEET);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    url.openStream()));
            while ((responce = in.readLine()) != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            Log.i("Responce:", "" + in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responce;
    }
}
```

Got error in this line:

```
String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
```

`LogCat`

```
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agrawalassociation/com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity.getSpreadSheetData(SearchActivity.java:173)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:114)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
08-13 15:55:18.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4157):     ... 11 more
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a logging line how ever you would do it, and check that the start and end are not greater or smaller than the length of result.

```
        int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
        int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
System.out.println("Start: " + start + " End: " + end + " results length: " + result.length());
        String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
```

I think it is saying that result length=0 and you are trying to access location -1, this may be because result is empty, and indexOf("{") does not exist so it returns -1.